# RecyclerView Layout Manager Manipulation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager

I have a recycler view that should display data as follows (1 item if position is even, 2 items beside each other if position is odd) and honestly I tried and tried but I'm failing to do so.

Here's what it should look like

[image]

And here's how it's now (ignore the width and height and see how video 3 is inflated twice)

[image]

I'm using LinearLayoutManager, and Here's my adapter:

```
public class MediaItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MediaItemsAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private List<MediaItem> allMediaItems;
private Activity context;
private RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MediaItemsAdapter(Activity context, List<MediaItem> allMediaItems, RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener itemClickListener ) {

    this.allMediaItems = allMediaItems;
    this.context = context;
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    MediaItem mediaItem = allMediaItems.get(position);

    if(position %2 == 0){ // even

        holder.tvTitle.setText(mediaItem.getTitle());
        holder.tvSummary.setText(mediaItem.getDate());

        try {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(mediaItem.getImageUrl())
                    .into(holder.ivImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            holder.ivImage.setAlpha((float) 1);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            Log.wtf("error", "in loading");
                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.ivPlay.setVisibility(mediaItem.isVideo() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }else{ //odd

        holder.tvTitle.setText(mediaItem.getTitle());
        holder.tvSummary.setText(mediaItem.getDate());

        try {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(mediaItem.getImageUrl())
                    .into(holder.ivImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            holder.ivImage.setAlpha((float) 1);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            Log.wtf("error", "in loading");
                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.ivPlay.setVisibility(mediaItem.isVideo() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        try{

            MediaItem secondMediaItem = allMediaItems.get(position + 1);
            holder.tvSecondTitle.setText(secondMediaItem.getTitle());
            holder.tvSecondSummary.setText(secondMediaItem.getDate());

            try {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(secondMediaItem.getImageUrl())
                        .into(holder.ivSecondImage, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                holder.ivSecondImage.setAlpha((float) 1);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                Log.wtf("error", "in loading");
                            }
                        });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            holder.ivSecondPlay.setVisibility(secondMediaItem.isVideo() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position %2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.allMediaItems.size();
}


public interface RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(View v, int position);
}

public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView;

    if (viewType == 0 ){

        layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.even_media_layout, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder rcv = new RecyclerViewHolder(layoutView);
        return (rcv);
    }else{

        layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.odd_media_layout, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder rcv = new RecyclerViewHolder(layoutView);
        return (rcv);
    }
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView tvTitle, tvSecondTitle, tvSummary, tvSecondSummary;
    private ImageView ivImage, ivSecondImage;
    private ImageButton ivPlay, ivSecondPlay;

    protected View itemView;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        this.itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvSecondTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSecondTitle);
        tvSummary = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSummary);
        tvSecondSummary = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSecondSummary);

        ivImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        ivSecondImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSecondImage);

        ivPlay = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
        ivSecondPlay = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSecondPlay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onItemClicked(view, getLayoutPosition());
    }
}
}
```

How to prevent the data replication, how to tell the array list that object 3 has already been inflated? is there a better way than the LinearLayoutManager

Regards.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question might attract more interest if you would provide a [mcve]. As it stands, the question is too complex and has too many irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User GridLayoutManage to your RecyclerView and set span size lookup like this.

```
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup(){

        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return position % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is going wrong here

`return position %2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;`

See this

```
|0|
1|2
|3|
4|5
|6|
7|8
```

If you carefully observe the occurrence of items, items with multiples of 3 are having full width.

So basically your calculation should be like

`return position % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1;`

Little more explanation, even rows are having two items, but you are calculating for even number of items.

correct this part of the code too

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    MediaItem mediaItem = allMediaItems.get(adapterPosition);

    if(adapterPoaition % 3 == 0){ // every third item
       //your codes
    }
    //remaining codes
}
```

**here first thing is you are supposed to use adapter position instead of view position that is been passed as parameter. And next thing is you have to use third position here too instead of second**

> P.S. your adapter code is bit messed up, not sure whether correcting
>   this calculation will give you correct results or not until you do
>   little code cleanup.

Comment: I tried this return position % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1, but what i had is (first row one item vid 1, second row vid2 and vid3, THIRD ROW vid3, and empty layout beside it) why is video 3 always replicated

Comment: I already told, your adapter code is too big to debug currently, and I assume that you have many more calculation errors in your adapter.

Comment: OK, I found out other bug, updating it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **Adapter delegates**, obviously you can do it without it, but it will help you in the further development.

[Here](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates) you can read about it

You should create 2 delegates then in `isForViewType()` return boolean depending on provided condition `return position % 2 == 1` and in the `onCreateViewHolder()` return relevant ViewHolder(you will have 2)